# tomar el max de dos valores en un case

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una columna que se llama Last Date cuyas filas se actulizan con los valores de dos variables, si se perfomo un examen fisico y los resultados de cada organo, pero cuando no se hace el examen fisico pregunta una razon necesito actualizar con la fecha mas reciente ya sea de la razon por la que no e hizo el examen o si se hizo  no el examen. la tabla es la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al inicio solo necesitaba ctualizar con performed y test name pero luego me solicitaron tambien hacerlo con reason
mi codigo inicial es este

```
select distinct(max("Last Date")) as "Last Date" , "Site ID","Subject ID","Visit Name","Physical examination performed?","Reason if not done","Date",
"Time", "Test name","Result","Clinically significant?"
from(
select
distinct(max(case when fe.cr is null then perf.cr1 else fe.cr end)) as "Last Date",
sid.siteid as "Site ID"
,sbj.subjid as "Subject ID"
,vis.name as "Visit Name"
,perf.val as "Physical examination performed?"
,reas.val as "Reason if not done"
,date.val as "Date"
,time.val as "Time"
,Case when test.name = 'Other' then other.val else test.name end as "Test name"
,res.val as "Result"
,clinsig.val as "Clinically significant?"
--siteid 
from....
```

Pero ahora estoy tratando de meter la variable performed y reason en el case para que me escoga entre la fecha mas reciente y lo ponga en last date y lo he probado de estas maneras

```
distinct(max(case when fe.cr is null then perf.cr1 when fe.cr  is null then reas.cr2 else fe.cr end)) as "Last Date",
```

o

```
distinct(max(case when fe.cr is null then (max( perf.cr1,  reas.cr2)) else fe.cr end)) as "Last Date",
```

con esta segunda me sale error de sintaxis pero creo que esta mas cerca de lo que busco

Answer (score 0):

Solucion >D

```
distinct(max(case when fe.cr is null then (select max(v) from (values(perf.cr1), (reas.cr2)) as value(v)) else fe.cr end)) as "Last Date",
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo responde esto a tu pregunta. Lee [answer]. Luego, acepta tu respuesta.